# How to display closest location on google map from a list of locations based on lat and lng

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have list of latitudes and longitudes of bus stops that I passed from controller to view (javascript).

We are able to display all bus stops on google map using their lat and lng.

sample code:
index.cshtml

```
<script>


var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

//get my current lat and lng
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

var markersArray = [];

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.stoplatLngList){

       <text>

             markersArray.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                 draggable: true,
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng('@item.stop_Lat', '@item.stop_Lng', false),
                 title: 'Whatever title',
                 map: map
             }));
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

we also have the user's current lat and lng. however, when we try to narrow the total list of bus stops to just ones within a specified range of the user's lat and lng. ideally we were considering an IF statement where we could subtract or use absolute value to establish the range within which we could get bus stops. however, we have been unsuccessful.

basically, how can we narrow the complete list of bus stops just to ones within user's range?

and just a little bit of my controller code

controller.cs

```
List<StopLatLng> stoplatLngList = new List<StopLatLng>();
ViewData["stoplatLngList"] = stoplatLngList;
return View();
```

Comment: What errors you are getting? Where is the code which narrows down the nearest bust stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question I've been meaning to ask is the best way to first narrow search down to city or the lat/lng coordinates of the screen but to answer your question: -

Throws a circle around the user's location of Xm radius and then search for bus stops in/out of the circle: -

```
Tier3Toolbox.EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137; /* Equitorial Radius instead of 6371000 */
Tier3Toolbox.toRad = 
    function (num) {
        return num * Math.PI / 180;
    };  
Tier3Toolbox.calculateDistance =
    function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
        var dLat = this.toRad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = this.toRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(this.toRad(lat1)) * 
                Math.cos(this.toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var distance = this.EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        return distance;
    }
```

Then I use a worker to do the filtering so that the UI event loop is free: -

```
importScripts("Tier3Toolbox.js");

var currVintage = 0;
var inBounds = false;
var facFilter = [];
var imageProlog = "<div style='height:5em; width:5em; display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;'>" +
                  "<img style='height:100%; width: 100%; max-height:100%; max-width:100%' src='";
var imageEpilog = "' ></div>";
var facilityTable, lineBreak;

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) 
{
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'init':
      initThread(data.load);
      break;
    case 'initFilter':
      for (var i=0; i<data.filterTable.length; i++) {
        facFilter[data.filterTable[i].locTypeId] = {'icon':data.filterTable[i].icon};
      }
      break;
    case 'filter':
      facFilter = [];
      for (var i=0; i<data.filterTable.length; i++) {
        if (data.filterTable[i].facSelected)
          facFilter[data.filterTable[i].locTypeId] = {'icon':data.filterTable[i].icon};
      }
      break;
    case 'search':
      var searchVintage = ++currVintage;
      var tableSearch = new searcher(searchVintage, data);
      break;
    case 'reset':
      reset();
      self.postMessage({'reset': true});
      break;
    case 'stop':
      self.postMessage({'success' : true});
      self.close(); 
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage({'success' : false, 'msg' : data.msg});
  };
}, false);

function initThread(msg) 
{
    facilityTable = JSON.parse(msg);
    reset();

    self.postMessage({'success' : true, 
                      'cnt'     : facilityTable.length
                    });     
}   

function reset() 
{
    for (var i=0; i<facilityTable.length; i++) {
        facilityTable[i].visible=false
    }
    currVintage = 0;
}   

function searcher(searchVintage, msg)
{
    var myVintage = searchVintage;
    var facIndex  = -1;
    var msg       = msg;

    var checkLoop = function()
    {
        if (myVintage != currVintage)
            return;

        if (++facIndex == facilityTable.length)
            return;

        inBounds = geoFencer.call(this, msg);

        if (inBounds) {
            var facMatch = 0;
            var bubbleHTML = "";
            for (var i=0; i<facilityTable[facIndex].facilities.length; i++){
                var currFac = facilityTable[facIndex].facilities[i];
                if (facFilter[currFac.locTypeId] != undefined) {
                    if (facMatch != 0) {
                        lineBreak = (facMatch / 3);
                        if (lineBreak == lineBreak.toFixed(0)) {
                            bubbleHTML += "<br />";
                        }
                    }
                    facMatch++;
                    bubbleHTML += imageProlog + facFilter[currFac.locTypeId].icon + imageEpilog;

                }
            }
            if (facMatch == 0) {
                inBounds = false;
            }
        }

        if (inBounds != facilityTable[facIndex].visible) {
            self.postMessage({'match'       : inBounds,
                              'facIndex'    : facIndex,
                              'scopeVintage': msg.scopeVintage,
                              'bubbleHTML'  : bubbleHTML,
                              'success'     : true
                            }); 
            facilityTable[facIndex].visible = inBounds;
        }

        setTimeout(checkLoop,0);
    }

    var circleCheck = function(msg) 
    {
        var diff = Tier3Toolbox.calculateDistance(
                        msg.centerLat,
                        msg.centerLng,
                        facilityTable[facIndex].searchLat,
                        facilityTable[facIndex].searchLng);

        if (msg.radius > diff)
            return true;        

        return false;
    }

    var rectangleCheck = function(msg) 
    {
        if (facilityTable[facIndex].searchLat > msg.SWLat &&
            facilityTable[facIndex].searchLat < msg.NELat &&
            facilityTable[facIndex].searchLng > msg.SWLng &&
            facilityTable[facIndex].searchLng < msg.NELng)
            return true;        

        return false;
    }

    var GEOFENCER = [circleCheck,rectangleCheck];
    var geoFencer = GEOFENCER[msg.checker];

    setTimeout(checkLoop,0);
    return this;
}
```